# Create Table (Data Management), Unable to Save to Feature Dataset

Tags: python, arcgis-10.1, table

I'm trying to create a table in a feature dataset and get the error: Parameters are not valid. The code works when I write only to the gdb. Am I not allowed to write to a feature dataset or am I doing something wrong?

```
import arcpy
import datetime

now = datetime.date.today()
exoticPlant = "Kudzu"
outPath = r"V:\chat_gis\gis_projects\Vegetation_Managment\Data\Derived_Data\Derived_Data.gdb\Report_01_14_2013"
exoticReportTemplate = "\MASTER_Data\VegetationManagment_Chatt.gdb\Exotic_Report_Template"
exoticReportName = exoticPlant + "_UnitCoverage_5years_" + now.strftime("%m%d%Y")

arcpy.CreateTable_management(outPath, exoticReportName, exoticReportTemplate)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In geodatabases, tables cannot be stored in a feature dataset.  They can only be stored at the geodatabase level.  Feature datasets are limited to feature classes and other advanced dataset types like topology, etc.

Check out the ArcGIS help regarding Feature Datasets: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//002300000001000000

Answer (score 1):

I've had a lot of trouble getting arcpy to save tables due to character restrictions I can never seem to get my head around.

The [validateTableName](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v00000025000000) function has been very useful.  Give it a look and try adding it into the code to verify that your table names are valid, that has helped me in the past.